# Can we find statistical correlations between columns of text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can easily setup a correlation matrix based on numeric fields in a dataframe.  I'm wondering if there is a way to do some kind of correlation analysis between two fields that have text.  Let's say I have two fields that look like this:

```
Field1
I wear a women's size 8 in every other shoes brand  
Always been a lifelong fan of Birkenstock...        
The wife loves them                 
My daughter loves them.                 
My daughter loves them! Very comfy          


Field2
i wear women's size 8 every shoes brand decided order size based everyone's review. the size 7-7.5/38 r fits perfectly.
always lifelong fan birkenstock sandals suede straps...
the wife loves
She wears them all year round - with and without socks. 
my daughter loves them! very comfy
```

These are next to each other; just showing one under the other here because I think it's easier to read.  Anyway, is there some way to do some kind of correlation analysis between fields that contain text.  Thanks.

Comment: maybe converting the entries to their frequencies can help?

Comment: I don't want to commit to writing up a full answer about all of the different algorithms for how to tokenize text (which is what you need to do to start computing correlations), but as a start you should look up TF-IDF tokenizer and take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `difflib.SequenceMatcher` to find similarity of two strings.

```
import difflib

Field1 = """I wear a women's size 8 in every other shoes brand  
Always been a lifelong fan of Birkenstock...        
The wife loves them                 
My daughter loves them.                 
My daughter loves them! Very comfy"""      


Field2 = """i wear women's size 8 every shoes brand decided order size based everyone's review. the size 7-7.5/38 r fits perfectly.
always lifelong fan birkenstock sandals suede straps...
the wife loves
She wears them all year round - with and without socks. 
my daughter loves them! very comfy"""

s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, Field1, Field2).ratio()

print ("ratio:", s, "\n")

# ratio: 0.312
```

Comment: Thanks guys!  That's good enough for me.